# Android Chromecast sender app, cast button doesn't appear in action bar

Tags: android, google-cast

I went through this https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender
up to "Handling device selection" paragraph including.
I expect that cast button should appear in action bar, but it isn't. And I suppose that Chromecast device was not been discovered.

I have real Chromecast device and I registered it in Google Cast SDK Developer Console.
And I suppose that device whitelisted because I have access to http:// chromecast_device_ip:9222

I set "checked" for option "Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates" 2 days ago. And I rebooted the device after that.

Also, I registered an application in Google Cast SDK Developer Console. But it's not published yet.
I think it can't be the reason, isn't it?

I use DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID as APP_ID. But I also tried APP_ID of my registered application.

I tried sample apps from GitHub:
https://github.com/googlecast
Cast Tic-Tac-Toe, 
CastVideos-android,
MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android.
And in all sample apps was the same problem. Cast button doesn't appear.

In DIAL CLient app (author entertailion) all work fine. But I'm not sure that it is what I need to implement Chromecast sender app...

here is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testcastbtn"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.testcastbtn;

import com.google.android.gms.cast.CastDevice;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.CastMediaControlIntent;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter.RouteInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private MediaRouter mMediaRouter;
private MediaRouteSelector mMediaRouteSelector;
private MyMediaRouterCallback mMediaRouterCallback;
public CastDevice mSelectedDevice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
        .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(
                CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID))
        .build();        
    mMediaRouterCallback = new MyMediaRouterCallback();
    int isGAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
}

private class MyMediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback {    

    @Override
    public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo info) {
        mSelectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle(info.getExtras());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo info) {
        mSelectedDevice = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {      
    super.onStart();
    mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
            MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
                                MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  if (isFinishing()) {
    mMediaRouter.removeCallback(mMediaRouterCallback);
  }
  super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mMediaRouter.removeCallback(mMediaRouterCallback);
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
    MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = 
      (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
    mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.media_route_menu_item) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.testcastbtn.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/test_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/test_menu_title"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>


</menu>
```

Also, I got next errors in LogCat. But it not crashes app.

```
08-01 16:21:17.644: E/ExternalAccountType(547): Unsupported attribute readOnly
08-01 16:21:19.196: E/MediaProvider(21126): invalid album art, error creating album thumb file
08-01 16:21:22.249: E/dalvikvm(21520): Could not find class 'com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.remote.bi', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.remote.bh.<init>
08-01 16:21:22.269: E/dalvikvm(21520): Could not find class 'com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.notification.a', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.notification.ExternalPlaybackControllerV14.<init>
```

**UPDATE**

Leon Nicholls said that it is known discovery issue in the previous release of the Cast SDK. A new version 5.0.89 of Google Play Services should work fine.

I suppose that I have an old release of the Cast SDK.
In google-play-services_lib/AndroidManifest.xml I see next

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="5077000" android:versionName="5.0.77-000"
```

But I have no idea how to update it. In Android SDK Manager Google Play Services marked as installed and there is nothing to update....

Comment: The few lines of log that you are showing don't seem to be related to your app. Does cast button show for, say, Google Play music or any third party app from Play store?

Comment: Yes cast button is appear in youtube app. Also I can cast from google chrome browser(using chromecast extension).

Comment: Now I think it may be problem with old Cast SDK. And I trying find out how to update Google Play Services in Eclipse. Because in Android SDK Manager it marked as installed and there is nothing to update...

Comment: @AliNaddaf re-importing the play services lib helped. Cast button appeared in the last 3 days. It worked just fine. All of a sudden it dissapeared a few minutes ago. And I have same problem again... I just noticed that updates for google play  services appeared in my android SDK manager. rev 19 become available for me. And now I see that my google play services lib is 5.0.89 version.
I didn't change anything in project, it just stopped working... In all sample apps too (VideoCast for example).
I tried re-import lib again, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to wait some time (in my case I went to sleep and after 8 hours it worked).